# How to display files of other format (.docx/.pdf/.txt) in Django templates

Tags: html, django, image, file

I am trying to show files that are uploaded in a Django Template.My model is as follows

```
class FileUpload(models.Model):
   id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True,auto_created=True)
   user = models.CharField(max_length=64)
   date = models.DateField(auto_now=True, db_index=True)
   time = models.TimeField(auto_now=True)
   text = models.TextField()
   image = models.ImageField(blank=True,null=True,upload_to='images')
   document = models.FileField(blank=True,upload_to='files')
```

When I uploaded the file I can display it in another tab using **admin**

[image]

If the file is an image then it can be shown using the **img** tag but what is the correct syntax and HTML tag for displaying the file in a Django template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can render it in template this way

```
 <a href="{{ context.document.url}}" class="btn btn-primary" target="_blank"> Download SLides</a>
```

Comment: This could be true. I am unable to find why {{ context.document.url}} is not working in my app. Have the same problem with images also. {{ context.image.url  }} is also not working. I had to do in this way for both the tasks:  
     `<a href="/media/{{ context.document}}" class="btn btn-primary" target="_blank"> Download SLides</a> `

Comment: the context is the name you provide in your view when rendering. So, is it working?